# How it can be increased or reduced the space?

Tags: tables, floats

I want caption and source in figure and table,  I would like to know how it can be increased or reduced,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption{Source: {#1}} }
\newenvironment{fignote}{\begin{quote}\footnotesize}{\end{quote}}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \caption[Proceso]{Proceso (Akarwal:2008)}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{example-image}
            \label{procesoClasificacionDatos} 
            \source{data}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:**
I can modify with `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{5pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}`

but the space the source is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may help you. for such purposes is defined the `copyrightbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}  % <--- new
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption[Proceso]{Proceso (Akarwal:2008)}
    \label{procesoClasificacionDatos}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}{source: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461754/}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you like to have source data in different color, for example in red:

[image]

than add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize % <--- you can select size as you wish
    \color{red}   % <--- you can select black or whatever
                }
\makeatother
```

to document preamble.

Comment: I would like the source to be more visible, it is very blurred

Comment: @x-rw, text is in gray, if you see blurred, than this is artifact of my cutting image from screen. you can change font size, font color etc as is now shown in answer.

Comment: How do I change the source and size ?, 11 pts and time new roman

Comment: font size in `copyrightbox`? replace `\footnotesize` to `\normalsize`  or what you like to have ... text is roman shape except in `url`, where is defined in its package. or you mean font size in your document?

Comment: If I put NORMALSIZE is the same letter that I have in the document ?, I need to have the same letter in the whole document

Comment: please be so kind and play a little bit with my answer :-). yes, it will have than the same font as you use in document. i added a comment to code which should explain this. however, color (gray) and font size (\footnotesize) have been deliberately select by package author ...