# how put source in tables?

Tags: tables

I have this code use copyrightbox, it's generated source in figure but not in table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}  % <--- new
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \normalsize
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption[Proceso]{Proceso (Akarwal:2008)}
    \label{procesoClasificacionDatos}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}{source: elaboracion propia proceso \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461754/}}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{table}[!ht]
     \caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\label{tab:aaaaaaaa}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}}\toprule
       \multicolumn{10}{c}{Outputs} & 33 & 3 & 3 & 3 & Clock \\ \midrule
       & & & & & & & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $t_0$ \\
       & & & & & & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $t_1$ \\
       & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \vdots \\
       1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $t_{10}$ \\       
       $a_0$ & $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ & $a_0$ & $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ & \\ \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use of `\copyright` box is at `table` the same as at `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  % of topic, better is to use utf8 coding
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \small          % <--- i would use the same font size as in caption
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select color on your wish
                }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
    \label{tab:aaaaaaaa}
        \centering
\copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}}\toprule
       \multicolumn{10}{c}{Outputs} & 33 & 3 & 3 & 3 & Clock \\ \midrule
       & & & & & & & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & $t_0$    \\
       & & & & & & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & $t_1$  \\
       & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \vdots           \\
       1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $t_{10}$ \\
       $a_0$ & $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ & $a_0$ & $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ & \\
       \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
                }{source: table is stolen from somewhere \dots :-)}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i have a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461770/how-put-source-to-algorithm please help me