# How put source to algorithm?

Tags: listings

I want to put SOURCE in the algorithm as I put them ?, I want to use this \usepackage{copyrightbox}

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algoritmo}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Indice de \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms

\begin{document}


\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}
[lipsum]
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{second chapter}
\section{First section}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...we need more detail. Where do you want it?

Comment: `lstlisting` as well `verbatim` doesn't work inside macros (as the `copyrightbox` is. you can emulate it functions with: `{\small source: unknown \dots\par\medskip}` immediately after `\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: @Zarko 
then how could I simulate and what remains the same as in the pictures and tables?

Comment: @x-rw, as i told you in comment. result should be very similar.

Comment: @Zarko I'm new to latex please, i need a example

Answer (score 3):

let me extend my comment to an answer ...

- `lstlisting` as well verbatim doesn't work inside macros (what the `copyrightbox` is).
- you can emulate its functions with:

  ```
  {\small source: unknown \dots\par\medskip}
  ```

  which you insert immediately after `\end{lstlisting}`
- another possibilities is to define new command in preamble, for example

  ```
  \newcommand\source[1]{\hfill\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}{
                          \vspace*{-1ex}\noindent\small
                          source: #1
                          \par\medskip}
                          }
  ```

  and than use as before.
- both cases you can see in mwe below:

  ```
  \documentclass{book}

  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algoritmo}% Listing -> Algorithm
  \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Indice de \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings and  Algorithms

  \newcommand\source[1]{\hfill\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}{
                          \vspace*{-1ex}\noindent\small
                          source: #1
                          \par\medskip}
                          }
  \begin{document}
      \chapter{A chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \lipsum[11]
  \medskip
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
  x=a+b
  };
  \end{lstlisting}
      {\small source: unknown \dots\par\medskip}  % <--- defined "in-line"
  \lipsum[11]
  \medskip
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
  x=a+b
  };
  \end{lstlisting}
      \source{unknown \dots}  % <--- used newcommand defined in preamble

      \chapter{second chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \medskip
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
  x=a+b
  };
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]